# Bamboo and Web UI Testing

Tags: user-interface, testing, automated-tests, bamboo

We have a node.js project that we are building with Atlassian Bamboo. We are doing CI/CD, or that's the plan. We are using Mocha to do Unit/API testing. But I didn't see anything in the task types to do web UI testing. We have used Selenium in the past, and that was the idea this time as well. But there is no nice, easy to use test runner and parser, as there is with Mocha.

Anyone have any experience with this in Bamboo? Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Selenium with Bamboo and I have configured Maven plugin and TestNG Parser . You can pass Selenium Grid URL/Base URL etc in environment variables.